# Deploy Heroku/Laravel - Forbidden - Sem Permissão

Tags: laravel, heroku, web-deployment

I’m with a problem in deploy to heroku, using a application laravel. Initially only I created a application laravel default and add:

- **Procfile**

  web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
- **composer.json**

```
    {
        "name": "laravel/laravel",
        "type": "project",
        "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
        "keywords": [
            "framework",
            "laravel"
        ],
        "license": "MIT",
        "require": {
            "php": "^7.2.5",
            "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
            "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
            "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
            "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
            "laravel/tinker": "^2.0"
        },
        "require-dev": {
            "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
            "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
            "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
            "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
            "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
        },
        "config": {
            "optimize-autoloader": true,
            "preferred-install": "dist",
            "sort-packages": true
        },
        "extra": {
            "laravel": {
                "dont-discover": []
            }
        },
        "autoload": {
            "psr-4": {
                "App\\": "app/"
            },
            "classmap": [
                "database/seeds",
                "database/factories"
            ]
        },
        "autoload-dev": {
            "psr-4": {
                "Tests\\": "tests/"
            }
        },
        "minimum-stability": "dev",
        "prefer-stable": true,
        "scripts": {
            "post-autoload-dump": [
                "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
                "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
            ],
             "post-install-cmd": [
                "php artisan clear-compiled",
                "chmod -R 775 public/"
            ],
            "post-root-package-install": [
                "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
            ],
            "post-create-project-cmd": [
                "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
            ]
        }
    }
```

Something which I verified too, in half of search in Internet went which Procfile need to be with the "**P**" uppercase. But inserting the Procfile that pattern in deploy alright generate the error:

***log Heroku:***

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> PHP app detected
-----> Bootstrapping...
-----> Installing platform packages...
       - php (7.4.14)
       - ext-mbstring (bundled with php)
       - apache (2.4.46)
       - nginx (1.18.0)
       - composer (2.0.8)
-----> Installing dependencies...
       Composer version 2.0.8 2020-12-03 17:20:38
       Installing dependencies from lock file
       Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
       Package operations: 62 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
         - Installing doctrine/inflector (2.0.3): Extracting archive
         - Installing doctrine/lexer (1.2.1): Extracting archive
         - Installing dragonmantank/cron-expression (v2.3.1): Extracting archive
         - Installing voku/portable-ascii (1.5.6): Extracting archive
         - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.22.0): Extracting archive
         - Installing phpoption/phpoption (1.7.5): Extracting archive
         - Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v4.2.0): Extracting archive
         - Installing symfony/css-selector (v5.2.1): Extracting archive
         - Installing tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles (2.2.3): Extracting archive
         - Installing symfony/polyfill-php80 (v1.22.0): Extracting archive
         - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.22.0): Extracting archive
         - Installing symfony/var-dumper (v5.2.1): Extracting archive
         - Installing symfony/deprecation-contracts (v2.2.0): Extracting archive
         - Installing symfony/routing (v5.2.1): Extracting archive
         - Installing symfony/process (v5.2.1): Extracting archive
         - Installing symfony/polyfill-php73 (v1.22.0): Extracting archive
         - Installing symfony/polyfill-php72 (v1.22.0): Extracting archive
         - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-normalizer (v1.22.0): Extracting archive
         - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-idn (v1.22.0): Extracting archive
         - Installing symfony/mime (v5.2.1): Extracting archive
         - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v5.2.1): Extracting archive
         - Installing symfony/http-client-contracts (v2.3.1): Extracting archive
         - Installing psr/event-dispatcher (1.0.0): Extracting archive
         - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts (v2.2.0): Extracting archive
         - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v5.2.1): Extracting archive
         - Installing psr/log (1.1.3): Extracting archive
         - Installing symfony/error-handler (v5.2.1): Extracting archive
         - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v5.2.1): Extracting archive
         - Installing symfony/finder (v5.2.1): Extracting archive
         - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-grapheme (v1.22.0): Extracting archive
         - Installing symfony/string (v5.2.1): Extracting archive
         - Installing psr/container (1.0.0): Extracting archive
         - Installing symfony/service-contracts (v2.2.0): Extracting archive
         - Installing symfony/console (v5.2.1): Extracting archive
         - Installing symfony/polyfill-iconv (v1.22.0): Extracting archive
         - Installing egulias/email-validator (2.1.25): Extracting archive
         - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v6.2.5): Extracting archive
         - Installing ramsey/collection (1.1.3): Extracting archive
         - Installing brick/math (0.9.2): Extracting archive
         - Installing ramsey/uuid (4.1.1): Extracting archive
         - Installing psr/simple-cache (1.0.1): Extracting archive
         - Installing opis/closure (3.6.1): Extracting archive
         - Installing symfony/translation-contracts (v2.3.0): Extracting archive
         - Installing symfony/translation (v5.2.1): Extracting archive
         - Installing nesbot/carbon (2.43.0): Extracting archive
         - Installing monolog/monolog (2.2.0): Extracting archive
         - Installing league/mime-type-detection (1.7.0): Extracting archive
         - Installing league/flysystem (1.1.3): Extracting archive
         - Installing league/commonmark (1.5.7): Extracting archive
         - Installing laravel/framework (v7.30.4): Extracting archive
         - Installing fideloper/proxy (4.4.1): Extracting archive
         - Installing asm89/stack-cors (1.3.0): Extracting archive
         - Installing fruitcake/laravel-cors (v1.0.6): Extracting archive
         - Installing ralouphie/getallheaders (3.0.3): Extracting archive
         - Installing psr/http-message (1.0.1): Extracting archive
         - Installing guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.7.0): Extracting archive
         - Installing guzzlehttp/promises (1.4.0): Extracting archive
         - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.5.5): Extracting archive
         - Installing nikic/php-parser (v4.10.4): Extracting archive
         - Installing dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir (v0.1.1): Extracting archive
         - Installing psy/psysh (v0.10.6): Extracting archive
         - Installing laravel/tinker (v2.6.0): Extracting archive
       Package fzaninotto/faker is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
       Package phpunit/php-token-stream is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
       Generating optimized autoload files
       > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
       > @php artisan package:discover --ansi
       Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
       Discovered Package: fruitcake/laravel-cors
       Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
       Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
       Package manifest generated successfully.
       44 packages you are using are looking for funding.
       Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
       > php artisan clear-compiled
       Compiled services and packages files removed!
       > chmod -R 775 public/
-----> Preparing runtime environment...
-----> Checking for additional extensions to install...
-----> Discovering process types
 !     Push failed: cannot parse Procfile.
 !     Please try pushing again.
 !     If the problem persists, see https://help.heroku.com/ and provide Request ID 4c5a16cd-17da-959b-0f2c-20c06971f06b.
```

I tried too run in deploy with the Procfile with the "**P**" lowercase, and the run deploy without errors, but the screen continue without permission.

Will be missing more something configuration, I’m following the tutorial of self [heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-laravel) and continue with the error

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: The reason it isn't erroring when you call the file `procfile` is that a file called `procfile` doesn't do anything. It _must_ be called `Procfile`, and yours has some kind of problem: "Push failed: cannot parse Procfile". What encoding does that file have?

Comment: The encoding stayed with UTF-16 LE

Comment: That's likely your problem. Save it as UTF-8, commit, and redeploy.

Comment: Now everything is fine, I just had a problem with the "500 server error", but it was easy to solve with a [Setting up a Laravel encryption key](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-laravel#setting-a-laravel-encryption-key), Thanks so much for help!